# Extended Toolkit WPF DateTimePicker Seconds precision

Tags: wpf, datetimepicker, toolkit

I am using the WPF Extended Toolkit's DateTimePicker. However, when I open the calendar to pick a date, it is only possible to spin hour and minutes. The seconds can only be changed when the calendar is closed.

I would like to add seconds to the time shown below the calendar when picking a date, in a way it is consistent with the time shown below.

Comment: it is reported [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home), but you may want to [submit an issue](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you need to specify a TimeFormat that contains a format to show the seconds e.g.

```
<extToolkit:DateTimePicker Format="ShortTime" TimeFormat="Custom" TimeFormatString="hh:mm:ss" />
```

The timeformat is used to display / control the editing of the time when the drop down calendar is displayed.